# Listview rounded corner selector issue

Tags: java, android, sql

I'm a newbie in Android so pardon my ignorance. So basically I'm doing a custom listview wherein I have chosen it to be rounded on its corners. What I'm doing right now is about the listSelector. I'm looking up from [this](http://blog.synyx.de/2011/11/android-listview-with-rounded-corners/comment-page-1/#comment-2695) post  and applied what the author posted, but I'm having an issue in pressing the top and bottom list. The highlight is still rectangle not rounded.

**UPDATE:**

```
   public class CustomAdapter extends CursorAdapter
{
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

  @Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
 }
}

   @Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

  int position = cursor.getPosition();

  int mCount = cursor.getCount();

    if (position == 0) && mCount == 1) {
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_rounded_corner_top);
    } else if (position == 0) {
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_rounded_corner_top);
    } else if (position == mCount - 1) {
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner_bottom);
    } else {
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_entry_middle);
    }
```

**SELECTOR_ROUNDED_CORNER_TOP.XML**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_corner_pressed_top"
      android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_corner_top"
      android:state_focused="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_corner_top" />
</selector>
```

rounded_corner_pressed_top.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item>
  <shape>
      <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#0000" />
        <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
     />
  </shape>
  </item>
  <item android:top="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp">
  <shape >
       <solid android:color="#FFB84D" />
       <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="8dp" />
  </shape>
  </item>

  </layer-list>
```

Any help will do and be appreciated.

Comment: where is the rest of your code?

Comment: @user2045570 I've updated my post. Please do check. thanks

Comment: I meant the rest of the code for you adapter @Dunkey

Comment: @user2045570 I've added the rest of the code of adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the problem by adding

```
    android:cacheColorHint="#0000"
    android:listSelector="#0000"
```

to my listview.

Cheers!